# Table cell validation in vuejs and laravel 5.4

Tags: dynamic, html-table, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I’m very new to VUE and trying loop through dynamically created tables from unique arrays. I have the table creation complete and dynamic table id’s based off a value from the array. I’m trying to validate that either cell[0] in each row contains a specific string or if the last cell[?] which has a select dropdown has been selected and is said string.

I’ve done something similar before in JS like this.

`$("#" + t_node + " :selected").each(function (i,sel) { .....///code }`

and like this

`$("table#"+t_node+" > tbody > tr").each(function(row, tr) { .....///code }`

I don’t know how to replicate with VUE.

I have a onclick event that I want to loop through the table and for any row that has p2vg01 already created sum its size along with any select option of p2vg01. In the below table I’d want to find that SDB was selected at 107GB. Not shown but it could be that SDB was already p2vg01 but if I selected SDC as well as p2vg01 I’d sum 32GB + 107GB.

```
<div v-for="storageResult in storageValidationResults" >
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{ storageResult.node_name }}</h3>
        <table :ref="storageResult.node_name" v-bind:id="storageResult.node_name" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" >
            <thead>
                <th v-for="(value, key, index) in storageResult.table_head">
                   {{ value }}
                </th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(value, key, index) in storageResult.disk_data">  
                <td v-for="v in value">
                   {{ v }}
                </td>
                    <td v-if="checkAvailable(value)">
                        <select>
                          <option value="">--Select VG--</option>
                          <option value="p2vg00">p2vg00</option> 
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td v-else=""></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You'll be validating the data that goes into the table, rather than pulling the data back out of the table and looking at it.

Comment: One of the columns/cell has a select input that allows them to select the intended volume group to create if it doesn't already exits so even after the table is created I need to validate if any tables row/cell had a selected value. Also even if it exist they can select a cell to append the selected value to.

Comment: Still, you should be working with your viewmodel data, not the DOM. Selections in the DOM will be reflected in your viewmodel data.

Comment: My table doesn't show up in the viewmodel data, I'm assuming I'm not adding something to the table like I should. Not sure how to add a v-model value to a dynamically created table(s) there could be 1-10 diff tables created after one ajax call. I'll past my table structure.

Comment: So `storageResult` is the part of your viewmodel that corresponds to what's in the table. That's what you evaluate your rules against. (Also, you can update your question to include the table code, rather than sticking it in comments.)

Comment: How would I link the select option values to storageResults since that comes from Ajax and the select option dropdown is only added when the disk is available? I see the storageResult component but it only contains the Ajax array data not the last select column.

Comment: I think I have a solution. Not sure if this is the correct way using vue but I added an onchange to the select options which updates the storageResults array value for each row if selected. Then I can validate the new array values.

Comment: Your `<select>` should probably have a variable bound with `v-model`. Then you would look for changes to the value, rather than the onchange event.